# Quasi Likelihood for Gamma and Poisson

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood, quasi-likelihood

I am trying to re-work exact expressions from Generalized Linear Models by McCoullagh and Nelder where Quasi likelihood is stated as:
$$ Q(\mu,y)= \int _{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{\sigma^2 V(t)} dt$$ 
In the case of :
 1. Poisson : $V(\mu)=\mu $
Ans: $$Q(\mu,y)= ylog(\mu)-\mu$$ 
 2. Gamma : $V(\mu)=\mu^2 $
    Ans: $$Q(\mu,y)= y/\mu-log(\mu)$$
I do get the expression for $V(\mu)$, however, I am a bit unsure as to the role of $\sigma^2$  and how it can be integrated out of the final expression for quasi-likelihood . I have tried finding resources online which describe the underlying process/principles but my search did not yield anything useful. I would greatly appreciate if someone could step me though either one of the problems